# Can't identify the difference between iPhone and iOS simulator in xcode 7 beta version?

Tags: ios

I am using following code to make a call from app.In xcode 5 it was working fine. But in xcode 7 beta version , I am running my app on iOS Simulator and `if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )` is getting true for simulator. How ?

```
 if ([[device model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"] )
 {  
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:130-032-2837"]]];
 }
 else
 {
      UIAlertView *notPermitted=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support this feature." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [notPermitted show];
 }
```

Comment: That's more likely to be related to the version of the SDK, not the version of Xcode.

Comment: what is the difference between `SDK` and `XCode` in iOS. @trojanfoe. If it is different then which SDK we use for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to check wether you are running in the simulator or on a real device, I strongly advice you to use `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` define (included in the `SDK`)

Use it like this:

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
//use case for iPhone
#else
//use case for simulator
#endif
```

I use it in my current project, in `Xcode 7` and `iOS9 SDK`

EDIT:
As trojanfoe noted, this is a compile-time check, not a runtime check.

If you want a run-time specific check for the simulator, you can use this:

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice].model lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@"simulator"].location != NSNotFound) {
}
```

Comment: That's a compile-time check, not a runtime check and not the same thing at all.

Comment: You might be right, but it's working, and I believe this is what the OP wants

Comment: Whatever, it is checking the condition correctly @Loegic

Comment: You were right @trojanfoe . I was doing it as running time but doesn't matter. It it does  then please I want to know

Answer (score 0):

It won't fix the fact that you are not able to detect the simulator, but I'm pretty sure that if you ask if it can open that URL before, on simulator it will return no.

```
- canOpenURL:
```

Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:).

Answer (score 0):

Device or simulator is defined as build time based on the selected target. This is how you should do this by adding a category on `UIDevice`:

```
@implementation UIDevice (Addition)


- (BOOL)isSimulator {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    return true;
#else
    return false;
#endif  
}


+ (BOOL)isSimulator {
    return [[self currentDevice] isSimulator];
}
```

Then simply call:

```
[UIDevice isSimulator]
```